# Vaadin $server is undefined

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin

I try to call a java function from javascript using Vaadin 24.

I read this blog post:
https://vaadin.com/blog/calling-java-from-javascript

There, it is mentioned that I can get a $server reference on an element. But for every element I try, I get the error message *element.$server is undefined*.

I furthermore read https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/create-ui/element-api/client-server-rpc where it is said that I can use *this.$server* but it does not work either. $server remains undefined.

Is there a special kind of element that provides a $server property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you're calling must be related with a server side component and the server side component must expose the client callable methods by using the `@ClientCallable` annotation. For example, suppose I have a view (e.g. MainView) and I have a method that I want to call from the client side:

```
public class MainView {
...
    @ClientCallable
    public String getGreeting(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
...  
}
```

Then, if in the client I have a reference to this view, I can do `await theView.$server.getGreeting('a name')` and I will receive back the 'Hello a name' string. Notice that I used 'await'; I did this because the client callable method will return a promise.

A bit more complete example (for vaadin 24.3):

```
@Route("someroute")
@JavaScript("./script.js")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
    public MainView() {
        add(new Button("greet", e -> {
            getElement().executeJs("greet($0, $1)", "client",
                    getElement());
        }));
    }

    @ClientCallable
    public String getGreeting(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

The `script.js` file (must be in '/frontend' folder):

```
window.greet = async function(name, element) {
  console.log(await element.$server.getGreeting(name))
}
```

In this example, when the user click in the button labeled 'greet' then the string 'Hello client' will be printed in the console.

Comment: Thank you Bruno, now I understand that only components providing a ClientCallable annotation have a $server object.